# SQLite wildcard % with space

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i concatenate 2 LIKE operator as 1 for below query ?

select * from students where name LIKE 'abc%' OR name like '% abc%'

Please notice " " space after % wildcard in second like operator before 'abc'.

Comment: SQLite3 does support `REGEXP` though it requires a user defined function, which is not possible on Android.  Hence, your current query is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most databases, the `LIKE` operator has pretty limited pattern matching (especially if you're used to regex-type pattern matching).  SQLite is, as far as I can tell, one that fits that description.  No one `LIKE` pattern can do what you describe.

Comment: SQLite3 supports `REGEXP` which _can_ handle the OP's logic in one expression, though sadly this isn't possible on Android which does not support user defined functions.

Answer (score 4):

Just ensure that all strings have that space:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE ' ' || name LIKE '% abc%';
```

Comment: Yes, I was too narrowly focused on the question as asked.  This is a better answer from a practical standpoint.